# Laravel upgrade issue with Larasearch

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, service-provider

I have upgraded Laravel app from 4.2 to 5.5, and while resolving the issues, I got this error:

```
[2017-11-22 06:18:54] local.ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share() {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application::share() at /home/.../vendor/iverberk/larasearch/src/Iverberk/Larasearch/LarasearchServiceProvider.php:139)
```

Although the class is in vendor folder and I don't think I should touch it...going from assumption that the package actually IS working with Laravel 5 (which on package [source](https://packagist.org/packages/iverberk/larasearch) says it is) I think I may have something in my own stack that needs fixing.

Package extends from Laravels `ServiceProvider`, and the method in question is this one:

```
protected function registerCommands()
{
    $this->app['iverberk.larasearch.commands.reindex'] = $this->app->share(function ($app)
    {
        return new ReindexCommand();
    });

    $this->app['iverberk.larasearch.commands.paths'] = $this->app->share(function ($app)
    {
        return new PathsCommand();
    });

    $this->commands('iverberk.larasearch.commands.reindex');
    $this->commands('iverberk.larasearch.commands.paths');
}
```

How would I start debugging this issue? The `ServiceProvider` class doesn't have `share()` method, that's for sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue locally, and set up a forked repository of my own since the owner doesn't respond to either issues or the pull requests.

[norgul/larasearch](https://packagist.org/packages/norgul/larasearch)